# JPA: How to map one entity's property value to collection property of another entity

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping, openxava

I have two entities, naming Sport and Image.

As the title above, how can I map the value of property, sportId at Sport to the @ManyToOne collection property at Image? For instance, I want the value of sportId (eg. 1) to be displayed at collection property field of sportId at Image. How can I achieve this?

Sport.java

```
@Views({@View(members= "title; date; estimatedCost; attendance; remark; images"), 

@View(name="NoImagesCollection", members= "sportId; title; date; estimatedCost; attendance; remark")})
@Entity
public class Sport {

    //******************************FORM ID******************************//
    @Id 
    @Hidden
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="SPORT_ID", length=10, unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int sportId;

    @NoCreate
    @NoModify
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="sports")
    private Collection<Image> images;

    //******************************TITLE******************************//
    @Column(name="SPORT_TITLE", precision=2000)
    @Required
    private String title;

    //******************************DATE START******************************//
   // @Stereotype("DATE")
    @Column(name="SPORT_DATE")
    @Required
    private Date date;

    //******************************ESTIMATED COST******************************//
    @Hidden
    @Stereotype("MONEY")
    @Column(name="SPORT_EST_COST")
    @Required
    private BigDecimal estimatedCost; // Include the import java.math.*  BigDecimal is typically used for money

    //******************************ESTIMATED ATTENDEES******************************//
    @Hidden
    @Column(name="SPORT_ATTENDANCE", length=10)
    @Required
    private int attendance;

    //******************************REMARK******************************//
    @Hidden
    @Editor("TextAreaNoFrame")
    @Stereotype("MEMO")
    @Column(name="SPORT_REMARK", precision=2000)
    private String remark;

    //******************************ENTERED DATE******************************//
    @Hidden
    @Column(name="ENTERED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date enteredDate;

    @PrePersist
    private void setCreateDate() {
        enteredDate = new Date();
    }

    //******************************MODIFIED DATE******************************//
    @Hidden
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @PostUpdate
    private void updateModifyDate() {
        modifiedDate = new Date();
    }

  //******************************GETTERS AND SETTERS FOR ALL PROPERTIES******************************//

    public int getSportId() {
        return sportId;
    }

    public void setSportId(int sportId) {
        this.sportId = sportId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public BigDecimal getEstimatedCost() {
        return estimatedCost;
    }

    public void setEstimatedCost(BigDecimal estimatedCost) {
        this.estimatedCost = estimatedCost;
    }

    public int getAttendance() {
        return attendance;
    }

    public void setAttendance(int attendance) {
        this.attendance = attendance;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public Date getEnteredDate() {
        return enteredDate;
    }

    public void setEnteredDate(Date enteredDate) {
        this.enteredDate = enteredDate;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public Collection<Image> getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(Collection<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

Image.java

```
@View(members="sports; image")

@Entity
public class Image {                     

    @Id
    @Hidden 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    @Column(name="IMG_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int imgId;

    @Required
    @Column(name="IMG_IMAGE")
    @Stereotype("PHOTO")
    private byte [] image;

    @ReferenceView("NoImagesCollection")
    @Required
    @NoFrame
    @ManyToOne(optional=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="IMG_SPORT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Sport sports;

    @Hidden
    @Column(name="ENTERED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date penteredDate;

    @PrePersist
    private void setCreateDate() {
        penteredDate = new Date();
    }

    @Hidden
    @Column(name="MODIFIED_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date pmodifiedDate;

    @PostUpdate
    private void updateModifyDate() {
        pmodifiedDate = new Date();
    }

    public int getImgId() {
        return imgId;
    }

    public void setImgId(int imgId) {
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Sport getSports() {
        return sports;
    }

    public void setSports(Sport sports) {
        this.sports = sports;
    }

    public Date getPenteredDate() {
        return penteredDate;
    }

    public void setPenteredDate(Date penteredDate) {
        this.penteredDate = penteredDate;
    }

    public Date getPmodifiedDate() {
        return pmodifiedDate;
    }

    public void setPmodifiedDate(Date pmodifiedDate) {
        this.pmodifiedDate = pmodifiedDate;
    }

}
```

ListSportImagesAction.java

```
public class ListSportImagesAction extends TabBaseAction implements IForwardAction { 

private int row;

@Inject  
private Tab tab;

public void execute() throws Exception {
    Map sportKey = (Map) tab.getTableModel().getObjectAt(row);         
    int sportId = ((Integer) sportKey.get("sportId")).intValue();
    Tab imageTab = (Tab)getContext().get("CkSurvey", getForwardURI(), "xava_tab");           
    imageTab.setBaseCondition("${sport.sportId} = " + sportId);
    System.out.println("id================="+sportId);
}

public int getRow() {                                                   
    return row;
}
public void setRow(int row) {                                          
    this.row = row;
}

public Tab getTab() {
    return tab;
}
public void setTab(Tab tab) {
    this.tab = tab;
}

@Override
public String getForwardURI() {
    return "/m/Image";
}

@Override
public boolean inNewWindow() {
    return true;
}

}
```

Any guidance provided will be appreciated.

--Edited--

I have added the code for the action that map the value. I fail to display the value at the property field, although it is displayed at Eclipse's console.

Comment: I don't understand you want to achieve. Put a list of user steps and data obtained in UI in each step.

Comment: Step 1: User enters a data for Sport.
Step 2: User goes to "List" view, click on a in-each-row=true's button, which associate with the data entered in step 1.
Step 3: User does the file uploading at Image. The data with a sportId value will map onto the sportId property field at Image. (HERE IS MY ISSUE).

It is the similar post at SourceForge. You mentioned add getView.findObject() but still not working.

Comment: It's just a list action that do a file upload. In the OpenXava wiki explains how to do a list action and a upload file action. Of course, you have to write the logic to save the uploaded file in the corresponding entity property.